# window creation issue Python Gtk via Quickly

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly

I'm currently learning python and GTK so please forgive the noobish question,

I have a program (created in quickly) that has two main windows, that is to say that depending on context one or the other window is displayed, and if a item is clicked in the first window the second window is called.

This works well the first time the second window is called, but subsequent times the window appears blank, its requested dimensions are applied so I assume it is reading the glade file correctly. Did some part of my program destroy the widgets when I closed the window? if so is there a simple way to avoid this?

I can post the source code if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a common problem with closing windows. In the `delete-event` handler, make sure you either `return True` if you hide the window or `return False` if you destroy it.